# I deleted files from my Linux box's /boot directory and now it won't boot

Tags: boot, grub

I deleted files from `/boot` to save space, but now when I boot I see:

> GRUB loading, please wait ... ERROR 15

`/boot` still has files corresponding to the 2.6.32-27 version of Linux. But I deleted all others that did not have that string in /boot

How can I fix this?

Comment: Reinstall your OS, man (unless you have backups)... what did you think was going to happen if you went mucking about in the /boot dir?

Comment: Actually, you might be able to recover by reinstalling the boot loader.  If the kernel files are still there you have a shot (you probably conked `menu.lst` or other files important to GRUB).

Comment: This has to be a troll. Like that story of that person who wanted to clean up their `C:\system32` directory or whatever.

Comment: +1 for a) the humor, and b) the guts to post such a thing to the world. :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are some instructions on [reinstalling grub2](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Reinstalling%20GRUB%202) in recent versions of Ubuntu.

I'd recommend following [the chroot method](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#METHOD%203%20-%20CHROOT) as I think that will be the easiest and safest way to restore your system.

Additionally, the next time that you want to clean up drive space on /boot, you can use synaptic or apt-get to remove old kernels.  For example:

> $ sudo apt-get remove linux-image-2.6.31-21-generic

Comment: It is best (unless you know your boot loader and OS kernel *very* well) to leave the /boot partition alone. That advice holds true whether we're talking about Linux or a BSD or something else altogether...

Answer (score 1):

Well Error 15 reads "File not found".
Restore your /boot from your last backup.

Comment: Restoring `/boot` isn't going to be enough, the boot sector may need to be updated with the new files' location.

Comment: If it's going into GRUB to display a GRUB error message the boot sector is OK.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to reinstall grub, I think that recreates the boot folder.  Not too sure though, but it can't hurt...

Answer (score 0):

The MBR is trying to read from a grub install somewhere on disk which has now been deleted.

You'll need to create a grub install and then write it to the MBR. Check the man page for "grub-install".

Basically you need to run:

> sudo grub-install /dev/sda

to write create a new grub 2 and write it to the MBR.

You'll need to drop a grub.cfg file to boot up your OS though in /boot/grub. If you don't have one you can regenerate a grub2 config file using grub-setup.

Comment: Of course he can't do this if he can't boot. He'll need a rescue or live media image to boot from first.

Comment: sorry - yes, you'll need a live cd that supports grub2. I believe an ubuntu live cd will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

On a modern Ubuntu installation, you should enter

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-3.xx.xx-generic
```

for whichever kernel version you have.  This should run a 'depmod' and then create the

- vmlinuz
- initrd.img
- System.map
- abi
- config

files.  Finally, it creates a new grub.cfg.  Hopefully this is helpful.